# Sequential criterion of continuity (Proof with filters)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I want to check the following: (The reverse implication is easy to prove)

We have:$$f:X\to Y$$
$$\forall ((x_n):\mathbb{N}\to X),\quad (x_n \to x) \Rightarrow (f(x_n)\to f(x))$$
We want:
$$\forall W\in N(f(x)), f^{-1}[W]\in N(x)$$

Here N(x) are neigbourhoods of x and the proposition $$(x_n \to x)$$ is defined as
$$\forall C \in N(x),\exists F \in \{A\subseteq X | \exists i,\forall j>i,x_j\in A\}, F\subseteq C$$

Topological spaces are induced by a metric. Also we can add other reasonable assumptions necessary/sufficient to prove that implication, e.g. that space is non-empty, normed, Banach, Hilbert. (except, probably, that some space is a sequential space, which is kind of cheating)